# Why is AWS RDS replication failing on database naming changes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-replication, rds

Over christmas break our AWS RDS database replica enigmatically stopped replicating.  Like I said, the replication came sort of out of nowhere and the following log error was what we were seeing.

From running a "show slave status;" on the replica we saw the following:
    **Last_Error**: 1872
    **Last_SQL_Error**: Slave failed to initialize relay log info from repository
    **Slave_SQL_Running**: No
    **Master_Server_Id**: 0

After we saw these issues and realized replication wasn't going anywhere we stopped and restarted with haste to no fruition, and then we spun up a new replica.  The interesting part of the new replica was the naming convention.  Instead of the 'live832.whatever' it was 'live-data832.whatever'.  Things were working just fine with respect to replication until we switching the naming convention back to the original 'live832.whatever'.  We destroyed the replica and created a new one with the exact same steps and witnessed the same point of failure, but the logs were still showing the exact same errors as above.  My question is, why is this happening due just to a naming convention?  Does AWS maybe have some sort of pointer based on db names that it's using for the configuration, which is pointing back to that broken configuration when we do the name switch?  It's an eerie, annoying issue.  At the very least, replication is back to normal with the new naming convention and we're not switching it because it's working :).